# R: how to incorporate write.csv in nested foreach loop

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-foreach

I simplified the problem to below and I know in normal circumstances, I would not use nested `foreach` loop and I should really use nested for loop. However, I would like to know how this could be done using `foreach` loop or is it just impossible ?

```
processedAndTransformed <- function(j){
  df                    <- rnorm(25)
  return(matrix(df * j,ncol=1) )
}

# in normal circumstances, use for loop
for(j in c(2,4,7,9)){
    res <- foreach(i = 1:4,.combine = "cbind")%dopar%{
  processedAndTransformed(j)
}
    write.csv(res,file=paste("testing",j,".csv",sep=""))
}
```

Now, my attempt to convert the outer for loop to `foreach` loop is below. **Please note that the ** `write.csv` **function** is inside the outer `foreach` loop but outside of the inner loop.

```
# below code fails
foreach(j = c(2,4,7,9))%:%
res <- foreach(i = 1:4,.combine = "cbind")%dopar%{
  processedAndTransformed(j)
}
write.csv(res,file=paste("testing",j,".csv",sep=""))
```

The whole thing just fails. I do not understand why and how to correct it.

**Update:** Should be writing to a different file.

Comment: You should nest the foreach loops. You are not passing a loop body to %:% as I'm sure the documentation you have read shows.

Comment: Do you write to the same file? Do you want to append? Do it in order?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the code. I am writing to a different file. Not appending and order doesn't matter.

Comment: Is it not enough to parallelise the outer loop only?

Comment: The inner `foreach` loop is needed because my actual code within the inner loop is a lot more complicated than what is shown above and it does some heavy computation which is why I parallelise it in the first place.

Comment: I mean, if you have enough iterations in the outer loop, you can parallelize only the outer loop. If each iteration of the inner loop takes a lot of time (and if you have enough of them), then parallelize only the inner loop.

Comment: Problem is I am actually using `write.zoo` in my case. By using your method, I will have keep to appending to those files. Can you show me a solution ?